# C++ file permissions when automatically started by Windows on login

Tags: c++, file, io, registry, pipe

Problem: my C++ program cannot write to a file after reboot because it is denied access.

The program is added into the registry at the following location, thus enabling it during start up:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

The following snipper within the code is similar to the one that is causing the problems:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt", ios:app);
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

Because this snippet of code runs within a loop the file is repeatedly opened and closed, but when the computer is rebooted the program seems to loose file permissions to it, and .open says it got an Acess Denied error with respect to the file.

What is the problem here? How come the program runs when it is initiated by me without admin rights, but not when Windows initiates it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the problem is not in C++ libs but in rights that your application has when windows run it. So, try the following:

1) create shortcut for your exe-file;

2) in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...\Run` change name of application from `*.exe` to `*.lnk` (just to run application with help of shortcut);

3) in the shortcut's properties in the Advanced Security Settings section change OWNER to SYSTEM.

perhaps this helps.

Comment: BAD idea. Running your own known-buggy code as `SYSTEM` is a security risk.

Comment: I agree, it's not the perfect solution in security point of view, but if it works and no alternative options, it can be used with caution

Answer (score 1):

`"example.txt"` is relative to your working directory, which is probably different when run at startup. Add a hardcoded path to test this hypothesis.